# PHP Dom parser or Jquery load?

Tags: php, jquery, parsing, dom, load

I want to load in a page a div from an another internal page.
The div that i want to display is a cart.
I want to show the cart from my shopping website in the header of my blog.

I can use PHP Dom parser or Jquery load.

Which solution is the best (performance, speed to display the content)?

Comment: I have a shopping website run with magento for example : www.shop.com and my blog (wordpress) in a subfolder : www.shop.com/blog
In my blog, i want to display my cart from the shop in the header of my blog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're concerned about speed, reduce the number of remote calls you have in your application. I write this especially because of this sentence in your question:

> I want to load in a page a div from an another internal page.

You should not do a remote call here to obtain the scripts output but instead - as long as it's your code generating that internal page - invoke the code instead directly that generates the HTML.

Example:

- Call magneto subroutines to generate the `div`, as it's a framework you might be able to create a route for that.
- Create a template function inside your wordpress theme like `the_basket` that is outputting that chunk of HTML.
- Use that function within your wordpress theme where the shopping cart should be displayed.

Next to that display performance in a browser is always best, when you provide all HTML before displaying. That is, if the `<div>` is already part of the page when the browser downloads it from the server. That's also best network performance as there is no additional request as with ajax.

This method even tops ajax in any case if javascript is disabled or not working.